# How to get a value in ngOnChanges for using in another function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have Array @Input in my code and I need to get the Array value in the child component when I push the parent component. I managed to do it just using ngOnChange. But i need to use this values in my Arrays in another function, but when i call the @Input the value comes to empty. How i get the value of ngOnChange?

@Input in Children Component:

```
@Input() namePackage: Array<string> = []
@Input() estaticValue: Array<string> = []
@Input() valueBag: Array<string> = []
@Input() linkImage: Array<string> = []
@Input() amountBag: Array<string> = []
```

how return in normal function:
[console.log of the @Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niy7b.png)

how return in ngOnChange:
[console.log ngOnChange @Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymDN9.png)

The pushes in Parent Component:

```
    let bagValue = this.packageSelected.value.toString()
    let bagName = this.packageSelected.name
    let bagAmount = this.packageSelected.bagAmount.toString()
    let bagImage = this.packageSelected.imagePath
    this.packageName.push(bagName);
    this.valueEstatic.push(bagValue)
    this.packageValue.push(bagValue);
    this.packageImage.push(bagImage);
    this.packageAmount.push(bagAmount);
```

HTML in Parent Component:

```
<div class="past-information">
   <app-lunch-review-dialog [namePackage]="packageName" 
   [estaticValue]="valueEstatic" [valueBag]="packageValue" 
   [linkImage]="packageImage" [amountBag]="packageAmount" 
   [finalValueBag]="sum"></app-lunch-review-dialog>
</div>
```

My ngOnChange in Child Component:

```
 ngOnChanges(){
console.log(this.namePackage);
console.log(this.estaticValue);
console.log(this.valueBag);
console.log(this.linkImage);
console.log(this.amountBag);
console.log(this.finalValueBag);
```

}

I need to get the values in the image 2 and using in a function like that:
Ex:

```
removeFoodBag(i: any){}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @FolabiAhn i add my code, so if this dont help and if you can help me, my github project: https://github.com/Kock03/Restaurante - Components: lunch-details-component and lunch-review-dialog.component

Comment: You mean the value of namePackage or image 2 ?

Comment: the both, the value of namePackage  value is in image 2

Comment: You have to know that when "ngOnChanges" is fired, it will not send to you all your inputs together. If you have lots of different datas needed. I Recommend a service with a "BehaviorSubject" observable.

Comment: If you are getting an empty value for the `@Input` make sure first the value is not coming empty from the parent component.

Comment: @FolabiAhn in the parent component his inicialize empty, but I have a function in this component that adds the items to the array, but when I open the modal of the child component, all pushes in the parent component are already finished. I want to get this values

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that function calling in ngOnChanges only. Use simpleChanges, it will detect the value of the value change, then you can call that function so that the changed value passes.

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes['namePackage']) {
          //call that function with the changed value
        }
     }
```

You can put debug in chrome, and see where we are getting that changed value

Comment: and if i need to call this function in a click button? How i do that?

Comment: before you clicks the button, ngOnchanges will be called - Store the changed value in a different variable.